# Is it possible to group by rows over a column that is not part of the GROUP BY, that will become a FK to the Group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to figure out how to group by similar rows, leaving one column out of the grouping, that will become a FK to the grouping. I know I can do it using a cursor and temp tables, but I would like to figure out how to do it in a set based way.

For example, let's assume I have the following table:

[image]

Let's assume I want each unique group of Letters and Numbers by Color to be one group, and then I want to build a FK to the color.

So, for example, in the above example, both Blue and Black have the same row values for A (A 1 and A 2). So this would be one group. Red has a different group, as it has an extra number (A 1, A 2, A 3) so it would be a separate group.

The end result would look like this:

[image]

Is this possible? Or do I have to use a looping mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `string_agg()` to bring the letter/numbers together.

```
select c.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by ln) as groupid
from (select color,
             string_agg(concat(letter, ':', number), ',') within group (order by letter) as ln
      from t
      group by color
     ) c;
```

You can then join back to the original table to assign `groupid`.

Comment: Oh interesting. I had thought about pivoting these values up, but couldn't figure out how to do that since there was no upper limit to how many rows could be in a group. This solves that issue. Plus I've never seen string_agg before, so learning something new!